# Validate against different ranges basing on attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

Suppose to have an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Angles>
  <angle unit="DEG">45</angle>
  <angle unit="RAD">0,7854</angle>   
</Angles>
```

Is it possible to define an xsd schema that validates the angle number against the corresponding ranges? (i.e. 0 - 360 for degrees 0 - 2pi for rad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `degType` and `radType` something like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="degType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
    <xs:maxInclusive value="360"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="radType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
    <xs:maxInclusive value="6.28318530718"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then in **XSD 1.1**, you can use conditional type assignment:

```
<xs:element name="angle" type="xs:anyType">
  <xs:alternative test="@unit='DEG'" type="degType"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@unit='RAD'" type="radType"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@unit" type="xs:error"/>
  <xs:alternative type="xs:string"/>
</xs:element>
```

In **XSD 1.0**, you can

- use an `xsi:type` on `angle` in the XML that refers to `degType` or `radType`.
- use different element names (`angleDeg` / `angleRad`).

---

**Per OP's request...**

An example of the `xsi:type` technique for XSD 1.0 follows:

**This XML document instance:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Angles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
  <angle xsi:type="degType">45</angle>
  <angle xsi:type="radType">0.7854</angle>   
</Angles>
```

**Validates successfully with this XSD 1.0 schema:**

```
<xs:schema version="1.0"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="degType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="360"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="radType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="6.28318530718"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="Angles">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="angle" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Using Xerces2 Java 2.11.0.**

Comment: Could you provide an example of option one for XSD 1.0? Visual Studio 2005 xsd editor complains that I cannot declare element with same name within the same scope with different types

Comment: @sblandin: Sure, answer updated with example using the `xsi:type` technique.